# Detect when stored procedure call

Tags: stored-procedures, detect

Now I want to make an app that can show all stored procedure calls from my website into database. My problem is how I can detect when this procedure is called by my website?

Can you give me any advice to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Valentino

Comment: What kind of database software are you using? This will help us help you

Comment: Are you wanting to count the number of times each stored procedure is called? If you want that, you can create a table holding the name of each of your stored procedures, along with a counter. Just increment the count for that specific stored procedure when it is called.

Comment: hi AndyG , my DB is SQL !

Comment: hi CHad , I just want this app to test in my client , if the website call a procedure , it will catch and show all info about this procedure !